# I have a map array that has many objects in it and now I want to get one object to be filtered from that map. How can I do?

Tags: java, dictionary

I have a map array that has many objects in it and now I want to get one object to be filtered from that map.Array map having objects contains an objects that needs to be filtered.

Comment: show your code so that we can help you

Comment: What do you mean by `map array`? is it an array of map ?

Answer (score 0):

So assuming you mean [Map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html), and you want to filter out a specific object from the map, you'd probably filter out by searching for the first object. You see, a Map is essentially a table with 2 columns:

----------------

|Key |  Value| #1 
    |Key |  Value| #2 
|Key |  Value| #3 
......

The first column is really just a reference point, the *key* for the actual data. The second column, or *value*, is that actual data. So if you want to filter out a specific object in the "value" column mentioned above, you'd search through the Map using the "Key" column

```
Map<Object,Object> map = new HashMap<Object,Object>();

public Object getValue(Object key) {
  return map.get(key); //Returns a single "value" object. Voila!
}
```